# Browser mode for Google Chrome to test compatibility of webapp

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, web-applications, cross-browser

I'm developing a web app and want to make sure that it runs as intended on all major browsers. I've downloaded Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE to test the app, but I want to make sure it works fine on previous versions of these browsers too.

I know I can download previous versions of Opera from [here](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/?os=windows&list=all), and in IE I can select 'Browser Mode' from Developer Tools section.

Is there any way I can test my app on previous version of Chrome, FF and Safari?

Comment: In chrome you can change the useragent, try that!

Comment: Wow! thats a great feature I didnt know about. Just read about it being a part of Chrome 17 beta versions, but it has limited versions of FF, Safari and Opera. I saw that there is an option to add new User-agent in the settings tab, do you have like a link that will guide me to add user-agents of the FF, Safari or Opera version that I want?

Comment: http://googlesystem.blogspot.de/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html i've found in the comments this nice article: http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/

Comment: If you want to use native implementations take a look into the portable versions of firefox: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable#legacy

Comment: Thanks @yckart ! The howtogeek website link was very helpful! :)

Comment: Browserstack is awesome for cross browser testing. They support 2000 desktop browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never really had a problem with something not working in an older version of these browsers. The only compatibility checks I do are with older versions of IE. The reason is that a new version of IE changes a lot but the others come out with new versions so frequently and have automatic updating (you don't even notice it in Chrome) that not only is there (probably) not a significant change to the rendering engine from one version to the next, (pretty much) everyone using it is on the latest version anyway.

That being said, there are some websites that show you screenshots of how a page looks in various browsers.

[Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) comes to mind.

Comment: I totally agree! But there is always that 1 user that lives in ancient times and will have FF 9 or Chrome 16 (the minimum supported browser versions for my app) and will crib about it and file a bug. So thought of running these browser compatibility tests, just to make sure I have all the bases covered :)
Btw BrowserShots makes my life much easier! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brokenkeyboards.com/btfm/

http://meineipadresse.de/netrenderer/

http://browsershots.org/